# How do I configure a custom trigger in Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I need to configure a scheduling algorithm that is beyond the capabilities of Spring's in-build scheduling (basically "every 5 minutes, but only between 4:00h and 16:00h"). It seems that implementing the org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger interface is the way to go, which seems simple enough.

The part I can't figure out and that doesn't seem to be answered in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) is: how does this mix with the XML configuration? There doesn't seem to be any way of specifying a custom trigger bean in the elements of the task namespace (apart from the Quartz example).

How do I use a custom trigger in a Spring 3 application? Ideally using the Bean XML configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using XML to configure any but the two standard triggers is not possible in Spring 3.0. It has been added as a new feature in the 3.1M2 release, though: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8205

Thanks to Mark Fisher for [pointing this out](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-1539?focusedCommentId=71264&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-71264).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [DurationTrigger](https://github.com/tolitius/on-demand-scheduler/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gitpod/scheduler/trigger/DurationTrigger.java) I wrote a year ago.

```java
public class DurationTrigger implements Trigger {

    /**
     * <p> Create a trigger with the given period, start and end time that define a time window that a task will be
     *     scheduled within.</p>
     */
    public DurationTrigger( Date startTime, Date endTime, long period ) {...} 

    // ...
 }
```

Here is how you would schedule such a task with this trigger:

```java
Trigger trigger = new DurationTrigger( startTime, endTime, period );
ScheduledFuture task = taskScheduler.schedule( packageDeliveryTask, trigger );
```

Alternatively, you can use a CronTrigger / cron expression:

```xml
<!-- Fire every minute starting at 2:00 PM and ending at 2:05 PM, every day -->

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="simpleProcessor" method="process" cron="0 0-5 14 * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Check out this [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-1539) as well as this Spring Integration [article](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)

**EDIT**:

From the JIRA discussion, you can configure the `DurationTrigger` above, or any other custom trigger for that matter, using Spring Integration:

```
<inbound-channel-adapter id="yourChannelAdapter"
                         channel="yourChannel">
    <poller trigger="durationTrigger"/>
</inbound-channel-adapter>

<beans:bean id="durationTrigger" class="org.gitpod.scheduler.trigger.DurationTrigger">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${start.time}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${end.time}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${period}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

It is quite simple to use Spring Integration in your project, even if you did not plan to. You can use as little as the above scheduling piece, or as much as relying on many other Enterprise Integration patterns that Spring Integration has available.

Comment: Thanks, tolitius. I still don't understand how to schedule a recurring task programatically (if I'm correct your example is a single occurance); and I still have the impression that I can't schedule it via XML config (I would need the equivalent of the @cron attribute).What I realized thanks to your post is that a cron trigger is actually sufficient for now. I somehow forgot that cron syntax allows intervals -- '0 0/5 4-15 * * ?' should work fine for my use case.

Comment: yep. And the `cron expression` above is actually an XML config that you're looking for :)

Comment: The cron expression has limitations, though. Nothing I worry about right now, but I put that as a comment onto your JIRA ticket.

Comment: It really does not have any limitations for your use case. @Oleg-Zhurakousky gave you an example in a comment to the JIRA.

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to put a watch on the issue so I hadn't noticed. I don't think he is right, but let's continue over there.

Comment: From Mark's response to the JIRA, you can either implement your own trigger, or use the `DurationTrigger` above, which will also give you a fixedRate. And as Mark suggested, you can: `trigger="anyTriggerBean" on the poller`